# Incremen Values in Array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner.
trying to make a simple soccer game.
All values are initialized to 0.
select 2 different teams from the dropdown >> enter final score (cannot be negative).
On clicking 'Final score' button,
function should increment the value of 'Played' to 1 for both the teams.
as well as display in the table.

```
function updateTeam(winner,looser){
    if (var a = $scope.Ligateams.lastIndexOf(winner)){
        $scope.Ligateams.played = "1";
    } 
}
```

Code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/srBSjSIxpz4QBBVHF4rF?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I took a look here, found a few things. I did not change everything, but you should have the tools to make other changes (ex. updating the draw count).

1. You had two controllers, one was basically acting just to retrieve the list of teams. This complicated the manipulation of the data, so I changed to use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), and loaded from a .json file.
2. In your UI, you iterated over the teams, and stored the name. I changed this to store the index for the two teams that were selected. This is used throughout the code to access that team. Since iteration was already occurring in the UI, it made sense to store those indices vs. searching it again in the controller. This grants us access to the object in the teams array with which to increment values.

Relevant bits of code follow.

**Load Data via HTTP**

```
  $http.get('teams.json').then(function(resp){
    $scope.Ligateams = resp.data;
  })
```

**Using the index vs. Name**

```
<select ng-model="Matchteam2.idx" ng-disabled="editButton1">
  <option ng-repeat="Matchteam2 in Ligateams"
          value={{$index}}>{{Matchteam2.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**Accessing Team info in the Controller**

Now we can get the team object from the array of teams with the index.

```
var team1 = $scope.Ligateams[$scope.Matchteam1.idx];
var team2 = $scope.Ligateams[$scope.Matchteam2.idx];

team1.played++;
team2.played++;
```

**Accessing Team info in the UI**

Since the basic 'name' field is no longer on `Matchteam#`, we can access the name property on the team object in the Ligateams array, again using the index.

```
Goal by Team <b>{{Ligateams[Matchteam1.idx].name}}</b
```

Here's a sample with some things fixed: https://plnkr.co/edit/Yby8D0z8IIEGXNxlwX4D?p=preview.

Comment: This completely make sense to me ! thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :). If this worked as an answer for you, please remember to mark it/vote accordingly.